# Sharepoint 2010 Collection not being initialized

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I've got a weird issue and I'm not able to trace how to fix it.

What I'm trying to do is get the user's ID and comparing it to all the users in a specific group, with the goal to find out if this user is in that group.

I believe that it should all work, but I have an issue in the OnSuccess function when I am trying to get the enumerator for the groups.
The error is:

SCRIPT5022: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserGroup, "sp.js");

//found online
function getUserGroup(){
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
context.load(web);

var currUser = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(currUser);

var groups = web.get_siteGroups();
context.load(groups);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSuccess(groups)), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFailure));
}

function OnSuccess(g){

var isInGroup = false;
var groupEnumerator = g.getEnumerator();

while(groupEnumerator.moveNext() && !isInGroup){ //go through all the groups
    var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current(); //get current group in the enumerator

    if(oGroup.get_title() == "SPM Team"){ //is the group title named this?
        var collUser = oGroup.get_users(); //get all the users in the group
        var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator(); //get the enumeration

        while(userEnumerator.moveNext() && !isInGroup){ //go through all users in group
            oUser = userEnumerator.get_current(); //get current user in the enumerator
            if(oUser.get_id() == currUser.get_id()){ //is the user's id the same as the viewer?
                isInGroup = true;
                console.log("success");
            }
        }
    }
}
}

function OnFailure(){
    console.log("nope");
}
```

At first I thought that this was because the context.load(groups) hadn't been fully loaded in from the request from the server, but even after time-gating it for a set amount of time, it still did not work.

Any Idea as to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserGroup, "sp.js");

        //found online
        function getUserGroup() {
            var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            context.load(web);

            var currUser = web.get_currentUser();
            context.load(currUser);

            var groups = web.get_siteGroups();
            context.load(groups);

            context.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this,
                    function () {

                        var isInGroup = false;
                        var groupEnumerator = groups.getEnumerator();

                        while (groupEnumerator.moveNext() && !isInGroup) { //go through all the groups
                            var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current(); //get current group in the enumerator

                            if (oGroup.get_title() == "SPM Team") { //is the group title named this?
                                var collUser = oGroup.get_users(); //get all the users in the group

                                context.load(collUser);
                                context.executeQueryAsync(
                                    Function.createDelegate(this,
                                        function () {
                                            var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator(); //get the enumeration
                                            while (userEnumerator.moveNext() && !isInGroup) { //go through all users in group
                                                oUser = userEnumerator.get_current(); //get current user in the enumerator
                                                if (oUser.get_id() == currUser.get_id()) { //is the user's id the same as the viewer?
                                                    isInGroup = true;
                                                    console.log("success");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }),
                                    Function.createDelegate(this,
                                        function (sender, args) {
                                            console.log(args);
                                        }));

                            }
                        }
                    }),
                Function.createDelegate(this,
                    function OnFailure() {
                        console.log("nope");
                    }));
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one question though, if one of my 'users' is a group within that permission group, how would I go about expanding it further? In this case, the "SPM Team" group has some users, and then another group that contains all of SPM Team, as sort of an alias in a way.

Comment: For expanding, you could add parameters in your custom function, based on parameters, achieve different logic. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39731/pass-parameters-in-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-in-javascript-client-object-m